# Correct syntax for setCACert ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to use a cert with an ESP8266. The identical code works fine on ab ESP32, but in the ESP8266 I am getting errors.

I set the cert as follows:

```
const char *ROOT_CERT PROGMEM = R"EOF(= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFYDCCBEigAwIBAgIQQAF3ITfU6UK47naqPGQKtzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
...
-----END CERTIFICATE--------)EOF";
```

For the ESP32 I use:

```
wifiClient.setCACert(ROOT_CERT)
```

This works fine, but on the 8266 I get:

```
no matching function for call to 'BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure::setCACert(const char*&)'
```

I have done some research and there are some suggestions the length is required, so I tried that also:

```
 wifiClient.setCACert(ROOT_CERT, sizeof(ROOT_CERT)-1);
```

But that produces the following error:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
```

I am using the 2.7.4 8266 board library as I have heard the 3.X has similar issues.

I have tried V 3.X but I get the following:

```
class BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setCACert'
```

Answer (score 1):

i could not use setCACert with 8266.  you need to do it differently and i had to do some web hunting.
But finally i did get my telegram test working from esp32 to 8266,
here is what i did and hope that you can adapt it

you need :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
```

after your defines add:

```
X509List cert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT);
WiFiClientSecure client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtokenValue,client);
```

in setup i had to add BOTH of these lines (i initially didnt think i needed the 1st line, but apparently you do) :

```
configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org");   // get UTC time via NTP
client.setTrustAnchors(&cert);      // Add root certificate for api.telegram.org
```

this got my ESP32 code converted from ESP32 to 8266

Comment: PS- replace WiFi.h  with the ESP8266WiFi.h